# what is the appropriate inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

[image]

I dont know what would be the inner product and how can I show the inequality by that

Comment: Can you write the question using mathjax? People on this site really, really dislike questions which show no effort and use links to outsource even writing them down properly! Your question will probably be closed if it stays in this form.

Answer (score 3):

First define $f(u):=(u^2-1)e^{-u^4/2},\,g(u):=(u^3+2)e^{-u^4/2}$, so the inequality we want to prove is$$\int_{\Bbb R}f(x)g(x)dx\int_{\Bbb R}f(y)g(y)dy\le\int_{\Bbb R}f^2(x)dx\int_{\Bbb R}g^2(y)dy.$$In terms of the usual inner product $\langle h_1,\,h_2\rangle:=\int_{\Bbb R}h_1(u)h_2(u)du$, this becomes $\langle f,\,g\rangle^2\le\langle f,\,f\rangle\langle g,\,g\rangle$, which is just the result we were asked to use.